# Unknown i/o port symbol on 15-pin D connector

Tags: io, symbols

I've never seen this symbol before, and can't seem to find it on the web.

The symbol appears to be an exclamation mark partly intersecting a horizontal (h axis longer than v axis) lozenge.  I say "intersecting" because neither part occludes the other, the outlines just cross.  The dot of the exclamation mark (if that's what it is) is centered in the lozenge, and the height of the e.m. appears the same as or slightly greater than the length of the lozenge's horizontal axis.

[image]

Comment: (1) Can you show us a picture of it? (2) Is your question "what is this port?", or something else?

Comment: I just want to know what kind of port it is, in the sense of what protocol (physically it's a 15-pin D!).  I don't think I can get my scanner to resolve it,  but I'll try.

Comment: I'll have to draw it and scan that.

Comment: What does your motherboard manual say about it?

Comment: Take a photo with your phone and add it to the question

Comment: I don't have a manual that refers to this -- it's not a new part.

Comment: What is the brand and model number of the device with the port.

Comment: It has no further information on it -- it's a port extender of some kind.  It's mounted on a slot fascia, and has a ribbon cable running to a header connector.

Comment: Is the port yellow and/or connected to a sound card?

Comment: No, it's not connected to anything -- I never installed it.  I'm guessing that it came with some motherboard I bought during the Chinese Quality Disaster and put it aside to deal with later but never did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This icon usually indicates a **[game port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_port)** – an analog joystick / MIDI port commonly found on older sound cards until. (See e.g. [this Gateway documentation](https://panam.gateway.com/s/tutorials/Tu_949665.shtml).)

When connected to a joystick, most of the pins are used to directly transmit analog axis values. Alternatively, most sound cards can repurpose it as a MIDI connector for controlling electronic audio instruments.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for decoding it!  I guess it makes sense, visually, that it'd be a symbol for a jstick, but it's a little surprising since I'm not a gamer at all, so normally I don't buy mamaboards that gamers prefer.  I wonder which one it was.

Comment: Ah, a decade ago _almost all_ motherboards had it – as did most dedicated sound cards as well (see the note on its MIDI use – apparently it's still preferred over USB due to having stable, low latency).

Comment: It's interesting about the MIDI use.  I play a few instruments (badly) but they're all acoustic, so my only connection with MIDI is downloading tunes to feed into Sibelius for the sake of getting notation.   I used to use Sound Blaster cards, so I suppose they had one of these ports and I never even noticed.  We live and, if we're lucky, we learn.